# Performance of gameserver

Tags: java, networking

I've made a gameserver using the TCP protocol. I'm using the KryoNet framework if that have anything to say.

It's broadcasting players positions and names once every half second right now, however i'm not sure how low i could put this while still being reasonable.

How often would it be recommended to have a gameserver broadcasting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends totally on the kind of game you are making. For many games a periodical broadcast is stictly inferior to an on-change or query approach. But if you decide for the periodical broadcast you can determine the correct time very easily: Ask yourself how precise the player-positions are needed on the client (as opposed to how much the client can interpolate) and divide the location-difference by the maximum speed a player's position can change at.

Comment: It's not a floating movement. I have a grid of 16*12 squares, and players can click any free square to move there instantly. It is significant to the game where the player's standing.
Edit: I've tried just to experiement with me and a friend as the only ones on the server, and making it update 10 times a second improves the feel of responsiveness by ALOT.

The client only send requests to move their characters, the characters are actually on the server.

Comment: Then you dont have to worry about the part i wrote in parenthesis (the interpolation). With what you wrote i am worried that you seem to place game-logic on the clients: that is difficult to get correct. Dont try to get client-side game-logic correct by making the networking faster, try instead to either have all game logic on the server or use a negotiation-algorithm (advanced and only used where latency is critical)

Comment: There is no game logic on the client, the client just sends the mouse coordinates to the server which then handles the request to move :-)

Comment: excellent, so the correctness does not depend on the update-speed. now the only reason to have frequent updates is player-comfort - less *"you can't go there because someone else made that move first"*. Since this depends on player reaction time i estimate this should be around every 100 milliseconds.